# How to overcome missing data in Time Manager

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I am relatively new to QGIS, and while trying to use Time Manager, I am having the following trouble - the date field in my attribute table has some missing values, which are mentioned as '---'. When I tried to run Time Manager, it gave me an error. How can I over account for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to replace the '---' entries with some default(?) timestamp or remove those features. Time Manager tries to parse '---' and cannot make any sense of it. That's why it currently fails.